# How can i update cart item in specific div using opencart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to update cart item in basket `div`. Code working fine but cart item does not update when adding cart item, now it working when i refresh the page.

```
<div id="cart" class="btn-group btn-block custom-cart shopping-cart-menu">
    <div class="shopping-cart-menu-left">
         <div class="basket">
            <span class="number" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>"><?php echo $countProducts; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div
```

Please guide me how can i update cart item in basket `div` through ajax

Comment: You need some `DOM manipulations`. After ajax success callback, update the number using `.$('.number').text(updated_count)`

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks for guideline where i have to add this `.$('.number').text(updated_count)` ?

Comment: Inside ajax `success`/`done` callback

Comment: @RayonDabre can you please let know about file name. I'm new in opencart

Comment: How will I know your file structure ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm using Opencart 2.1

Comment: Hey @adnankhalid what you can do is assign your cart div with id such that it can be split in increments. Now each time a quantity is updated or at update click you can use ajax and update your cart. I did this in my previous project. However, the opencart we used wasn't vanilla until then, lots of changes and modifications

Comment: Please show your jquery code

Comment: share in git , i will do this for you